# Will coding done in android 2.2 work in 4.1 Jellybean Phones?

Tags: android, compatibility, android-2.2-froyo

I have wrote an application using android 2.2 in eclipse.

My app is working fine on the samsung galaxy mini android 2.2. However, it is not working on samsung galaxy s3 android 4.1.

My app is only taking up half of the screen on the samsung galaxy s3.

1. Why is my app not working on higher resolution devices?
2. How can i make the app compatible with other devices running
   different versions of android?

Comment: Can you say something more about what isn't working?  Generally 2.2 code should work fine on 4.1

Comment: Android 4.1 Jelly Bean is fully backwards compatibile with Android FroYo 2.2, so I think you made a programming error. Do you have a logcat

Comment: i don knw..i was using a broadcast receiver...it worked fine in froyo but not in jellybean and also screen resolution problems

Comment: How to get errors??..i exported and installed the apk

Comment: You will need to better describe the issue you are seeing. what and how was it working before, and What and how is it not working now. Also, if you are seeing errors in logcat, that would be helpful.

Comment: What is you're target sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it's most likely you just have a LinearLayout at the top of your layout XML and it just takes up less space on the S3.

I would advise taking a look at the two links below; if you want a specific starting point, you could adjust your layout to match_parent and use the l/m/h/xhdpi folders to place different size graphics in. Also worth checking whether you are using dp or dip (density independent pixels)

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/designing-for-tablets-were-here-to-help.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way to ensure that your app will work on other devices is to get access to other devices and test your application on those devices before you release.

Another way is to make sure that you are targeting the correct SDK you need to target and use the `AndroidSupportLibrary` when needing to have backwards compatibility.

For us to help with your specific problem we would need more details as to what exactly is going on, but make sure the packages and libraries you are using are compatible with the android versions you are trying to target.

And make good use of the `AndroidSupportLibrary`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the resolution compatibility? This seems more like an Android Manifest issue then an Android version issue.